# Return element class post form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create customizable checkboxes using buttons. I'm able to differentiate which button class has been selected, but I've been unable to track the button class post form submission. Ideally, instead of reseting the buttons to a default value when the page is loaded or submitted, I can keep whatever input was initially provided. I've tried using the isset() php function, but I don't think it's a valid solution in this circumstance. Are there any alternatives? Find my code below:

```
<form id="my-form" method="post">
<html>
<body >

 <style>    
  .button {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .button1 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
  }

  .button2 {
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
  } 
</style>

<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>

<!-- invalid code?
<?php
echo isset($_POST["t1test"]);
echo isset($_POST["t2test"]);
echo $_POST["t1test"];
echo $_POST["t2test"];
?>
-->

<script type="text/javascript">

  function makeButton(div, val) {
    var element = document.getElementById(val);
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    // change to account for submitted settings
    if (element == null) {
      button.setAttribute("class", "button button1"); }
    else {
      var cL1 = element.classList.contains("button1");
      var cL2 = element.classList.contains("button2");
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
      if (cL2 == true) { button.setAttribute("class", "button button1"); }
      if (cL1 == true) { button.setAttribute("class", "button button2"); }
    }
    button.setAttribute("type", "button");
    button.setAttribute("id", val);
    button.setAttribute("name", val);
    var testDiv = document.getElementById(div);
    testDiv.appendChild(button);
    button.addEventListener ("click", function() { makeButton(div, val); }) 
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    makeButton("test1", "t1test"); 
    makeButton("test2", "t2test"); }

</script>

</body>
</html>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing the form tags and adding a "click" event listener to the submit button? The code shown below inserted appended to the end of the file:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var elements = ["t1test", "t2test"];
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elements[i]);
    console.log(element.classList.contains("button1"));
    console.log(element.classList.contains("button2"));
  }
});
</script>
```

This way the page will not be reloaded when the button is pressed thus retaining button selection.

Comment: That should solve a few other problems I've been experiencing. I'll give it a shot and update. Will take a while to cascade the changes throughout my existing code.

Comment: I think this will work. I currently have a php sql query which requires the form to reload, but I should be able to switch to an AJAX method.